# Stored procedure for data excluding is not working as expected in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, stored-procedures

I have written a query where I want to exclude the data for which values comes as `_900`. Below is the query for the same.

```html
SELECT
TO_CHAR(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) AS SPAN_ID,TO_CHAR(RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE,RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID
FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER
--FROM APP_FTTX.SPAN_2@SAT
WHERE
LENGTH(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) = 21
--AND REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), 'SP(N|Q|R|S)*.+_(BU|MP)$','i')
--AND (NOT REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), '(_U)$|(/)$','i')
--AND REGEXP_LIKE(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID, '(%*_9%)','i')--)
AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = 'INORBNPN01'
and RJ_SPAN_ID = 'ORKPRKORKONASPR001_BU';
```

I tried all the commented `REGEXP` but it's not working.

Also, with the above query below is the screenshot for the output which I am getting.

[image: IMG]

Comment: Try changing your regexp to `not REGEXP_LIKE(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID, '_9','i')`. The `%` aren't used for REGEXP_LIKE. Also note that no regexp will match your `null` values - you need either an `NVL()` or `OR column IS NULL` if you want them included.

Comment: @kfinity: with your above regex, i get it 0 row.. atleast i should get `null`..

Comment: _" i get it 0 row.. atleast i should get null"_   And what did @kfinity say about that?  "Also note that no regexp will match your null values - you need either an NVL() or OR column IS NULL if you want them included"

Comment: As an example of handling nulls, try `not REGEXP_LIKE(nvl(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'ok'), '_9','i')` - that will replace your null values with 'ok' so the regex can match them.

Comment: @kfinity: also will it give other values other than `_900` right ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not `LIKE`?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '900'       from dual union all  --> doesn't contain _900
  3     select '123_900AB' from dual union all  --> contains _900
  4     select '_900'      from dual union all  --> contains _900
  5     select 'ab900cd'   from dual            --> doesn't contain _900
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where col not like '%\_900%' escape '\';

COL
---------
900
ab900cd

SQL>
```

Comment: it is not displaying `null` values, its excluding `null` values also